# Customizing the forms' savebuttons

Tags: form

I wondered if there is a possibility to change the site referred by the savebuttons.
The save button is supposed to guide users back to the hompage and not to the list the form is attached to.
I didn't find any Fitting answer so I hope to get some useful advice.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that Brandon's solution will work, because if you override the onclick handler of the Save button, the form won't be saved. You will just redirect user to another page. I'm a leader of [SharePoint Forms Designer](http://spform.com) team and I want to suggest our tool as a perfect solution to your issue. Please, note that it's not free. Get more information:
http://formsdesigner.blogspot.com/2014/01/publish-designed-form-to-any-page.html

Answer (score 0):

You can add script to the save button, which would be as simple as:

```
window.location.replace("your_new_page.com");
```

Just attach that to the save button with something like an onclick trigger, and it will redirect the user to that page.

I'm not sure what you mean by "can'T get into the form's script," but if you can add code to the page.aspx form, write your code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction() {
window.location.replace("your_new_page.com");
}

document.getElementById("ID_of_save_button").onclick=myFunction();
</script>
```

I'm not sure if the data is saved this way as well, but I'm sure you could use a timeout event to wait a little before a redirect.

Comment: Where am I supposed to add the script? I can't find any place in the form's script where the button is defined.

Comment: You can't edit the original source code of the webpage?

Comment: At least I'm not sure where I should look for it. Do you mean the sourcecode of the form?

Comment: Yeah, you can add scripts into the source code of the form. You include the script before the main place holder asp tag closes.